# waiting validation before recording data in database

Tags: database, django, triggers, transactions

I have a Django application where users can answer to simple questions.
For those questions, I have one or more tags specifying the expertise expected from
a user.

When a user answer to a question, I update the DB and I record the tags related to the question. Meaning that if we have a question with tags : rescuing, mathematics and geography,

I check if the user has already answered to such question with these tags. Let suppose that the user has answered 10 times for the tag rescuing, 2 times for the tag mathematics and none for the tag geography.

When the user answers, the DB is updated to rescuing : 11, mathematics : 3, geography : 1.

My question is that if the owner of the question is unsatisfied of the answer, I want him to click on a "valid answer" or "invalid answer" button.

By clicking on the invalid answer button I want to update the score of the user and decrement his score for the tags of the question.

I can't really see how to do it with Django, is it possible to start a trigger when clicking 
on a button that would record the score in the DB ?

I hope I made myself understandable

Thanks for the help

E.L

Comment: What have you tried before? It seems really a "code this for me" question...

Comment: I didn't try something, I was looking for an idea for a post validating function. I always set expertise when a user answers. But I found a solution ! I need to update all users when the question's owner validates the task instead of updating while answering. I was gone in the wrong way so I couldn't think in another way ! By the way, thank you :)

Comment: You should answer your own question so that it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple actually !

Instead of updating score while answering the question, I just need to get the list
of users who answered to the question when the question's owner access the answer page.

He can validate the task (meaning he is satisfied), so the score of all answerers is updated 
or invalidate the task and nothing changes for the answerers' score !

Thanks for attention ! :)